# How do I make it so that processes are created parallel to each other rather than one after another?

Tags: c, process, operating-system

I need help in modifying this code. Right now, it creates a process, and then waits for its termination. After which, another process is created, and then it waits for its termination. I want to modify it so that it creates both processes at the same time and executes them parallel to each other. The code is:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  pid_t pid;
  int status;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid != 0) {
    while (pid != wait( & status));
  } else {
    sleep(5);
    exit(5);
  }
  pid = fork();
  if (pid != 0) {
    while (pid != wait( & status));
  } else {
    sleep(1);
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't `wait` after the creation of the first process, but only `wait` in the end for all of the children...

Comment: @EugeneSh. May I please know how? It is literally my third code in C. I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Remove the `while (pid != wait(&status));` loop in both parent conditions.  In the second, use `int corpse; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);`.  If you wanted, you could add timing information to the printing.  You might also print the two child PID values before going into the wait loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thankyou so much for your help. So in the first if condition, I should just empty the body?

Comment: Forking and process management are non-trivial, certainly not a topic for a beginner-level student.  Do consider switching to a more introductory-level course.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am actually learning from a friend. He lives on the opposite end of the globe and has tasked me to do this. It's night time where he lives, so I felt the need to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's code that should do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid != 0)
    printf("Child 1 PID = %d\n", pid);
  else
  {
    sleep(5);
    exit(5);
  }
  pid = fork();
  if (pid != 0)
  {
    printf("Child 2 PID = %d\n", pid);
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
  }
  else
  {
    sleep(1);
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

One time when I ran it, I got the output:

```
Child 1 PID = 49582
Child 2 PID = 49583
Child 49583 exited with status 0x0100
Child 49582 exited with status 0x0500
```

If you preferred, you could move the `wait()` loop and its variable declarations after the `if` structures and immediately before the `return 0;` at the end.  That would give you better symmetry.  You could even wrap up the child creation phase into a function called twice:

```
static void procreate(int kidnum, int naptime)
{
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0)
        printf("Child %d PID = %d (nap time = %d)\n", kidnum, pid, naptime);
    else
    {
        sleep(naptime);
        exit(naptime);
    }
}
```

and then in `main()` you'd just have two calls to `procreate()` and the wait loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    procreate(1, 5);
    procreate(2, 1);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("Child PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the function `fork()` has three kinds of returned values: >0 means in the parent process,  ==0 means in the child process.   <0 means an error occurred.   the code needs to be checking for all three conditions

Comment: It could check for an error from `fork()`; it does not have to. The original code didn't.  This revision doesn't.  It will work more or less safely even if `fork()` fails.  The only minor issue would be that `status` is used uninitialized if `fork()` fails, an issue which is easily remedied.

Comment: just because the original code does not check for errors does not mean we should condone not checking for errors,  at least we should inform the newbe of the need for error checking